# Changing text in div in loop with delay

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following div:

```
    <div class="mytext">first</div>
```

I want to change this text after 5 seconds to 'second', then after another 5 seconds to 'third' and then come back to "first". Can you help me with that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate the text array or add up more elemets to display. Please check the snippet below. Use setInterval to call the function every 5s

```js
var text = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
function callMe(){
  var myText = document.getElementById('mytext');
  var curIdx = text.indexOf(myText.innerHTML);
  myText.innerHTML = text[(curIdx+1)%text.length];
}

setInterval(callMe,5000);
```

```html
<div id="mytext">first</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just construct method with setInterval() and trigger it to start in body

```
<head>
<script>
    var a = ["first", "second", "third"];

    function f(currentId) 
    {
        if( currentId == a.length ) currentId = 0;

        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = a[currentId];            

        setInterval(function(){ f(currentId+1) }, 5000);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="f(0)">
    <div id="text"></div>
</body>
```